# How to rename a column which have a same name with another one

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, rename

I have an data - frame as below...

```
  AA BB CC DD EE ... LL MM NN NN
0 a0 b0 c0 d0 e0 ... l0 m0 x0 y0
1 a1 b1 c1 d1 e1 ... l1 m1 x1 y1
2 a2 b2 c2 d2 e2 ... l2 m2 x2 y2
3 a3 b3 c3 d3 e3 ... l3 m3 x3 y3
```

I would like to change the name of 'NN' which is in right edge.

Somebody says you should use `dataframe.columns = [AA,BB,CC...,NN,ZZ]`.

However, in my case, number of columns is too many to use this method.

I have tried as below...

```
dataframe.columns[-1] = 'ZZ'
```

However, I just have got the script

> TypeError: Index does not support mutable operations.

Answer (score 0):

You can slice all column names without last, create new `list` with [`tolist`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.tolist.html), add new name `['ZZ']` and reassign back to `df.columns`:

```
df.columns = df.columns[:-1].tolist() + ['ZZ'] 
print (df)
   AA  BB  CC  DD  EE  ...  LL  MM  NN  ZZ
0  a0  b0  c0  d0  e0  ...  l0  m0  x0  y0
1  a1  b1  c1  d1  e1  ...  l1  m1  x1  y1
2  a2  b2  c2  d2  e2  ...  l2  m2  x2  y2
3  a3  b3  c3  d3  e3  ...  l3  m3  x3  y3
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy the columns to a new list, modify the last index of the list, and reassign back to `df.columns`:

```
>>> col = list(df.columns)
>>> col
['z', 'z']
>>> col[-1] = 'ZZ'
>>> df.columns = col
>>> df
   z  ZZ
0  1  10
1  2  20
```